# Is there a way to set transform units to pixels in Photoshop CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing, actions

I have a lot photos which I need to crop into 1080px wide x 1920px high.

I've set up an action that first unlocks the layer, changes the canvas to 1080px x 1920px and the transforms the image with a height of 1920px. (When recording the action for transforming, I locked the aspect ratio and input `1920px` into the height field.) After that I refine the crop and add other adjustments.

When looking at the detail I see that it says 187.5% width and height.

Is there a way to change that to pixels so that it will always increase the height by 1920 pixels rather than the percentage.

Images being cropped are all different sizes. I have also changed the units in the preferences to pixels. But it didn't work.

[image: Details of the action]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the image size (**Image > Image Size...**) instead of using a transform. The only difference being that you change the image size then the canvas size instead of changing the canvas first.

You can lock the aspect ratio (Constrain Proportions) and just input the height in the Image Size dialog exactly as you did with transform and the action will save the pixel value.

Comment: simple solution, I made it complex for no reason ... lol

Answer (score 0):

Try turning your rulers on before you record the action, and then right click and switch ruler units to pixels. I think it should default to pixels instead of percentages doing it that way.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. And the rulers are already pixels by default. I set the default to centimetres and then turned on the ruler and changed to pixels, that didn't work.

Comment: Sorry that is giving you so much trouble. I found this thread in the Adobe Forums: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2039079 . According to the thread, you have to make script and run the script as part of your action. As far as I can tell, there's not a way to change the crop units recorded in the action. Maybe someone else has more insight.